# Bluetooth keyboard disabled after logging in

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, bluetooth

I paired my bluetooth keyboard with Ubuntu 16.04. At first, it seemed to work. Then I opened the "Keyboard settings", and the keyboard does not work anymore.

The funny thing is, if I logout, then I can type the login password with the keyboard. But when I log in, the keyboard does not work anymore.

How can I make the keyboard work when logged in?

Note: This keyboard does not have a receiver.

Comment: The keyboard is working fine under LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Numlock is turn on by default. To solve it:

- Install numlockx:

  sudo apt-get install numlockx
- Turn off numlock:

  numlockx off

Personally, I add the command to Autostart, so that numlock is disable at login.

Related documentation: [NumlockAppleKeyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Numlock_on_Apple_Wireless_Keyboard). Note that the method to disable numlock in the documentation is outdated (16.04), as the setting entry is not available anymore.